# Scheduled Tasks Triggering When Not Scheduled

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

Server environment: Windows Server 2012 R2

Hello,

I've been experiencing a strange issue on one of the servers I administrate and was hoping someone could point me in the direction of some answers.

Periodically in the past this server has had downtime for various reasons (updates, unexpected crashes, etc). That's not unexpected - but each time it happens, some of the scheduled jobs on the task scheduler will try to trigger even if they're not supposed to run for another several days.

Initially, my research pointed to the setting on the scheduled task 'Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed’ being checked as the issue - but we just had this happen again today on a task which I verified didn't have that setting checked. I've tried googling extensively and searching ServerFault but all I'm finding is things not triggering, not things triggering extra times.

The history for this task only shows two events - initially one at 11:21 AM (at which point our server was down) indicating Task Start Failed with an exit code of 2147943711 (file not found - but I've verified the file is in the right place), then another one at 12:36 (right when the server went back up) saying 'Missed Task Start Rejected'. This wasn't supposed to run for another 3 days.

Does anyone have any information on why this might be happening and how we can stop it?

Comment: You can configure tasks to run based on triggers that are not scheduled, such as at log on or at startup. Also, it looks like there are system tasks that have no triggers configured but are somehow made to run at certain times anyway. Are the jobs in question ones that you or another administrator created, or were they automatically created by the OS (at install time, perhaps)?

Comment: Hi @ToddWilcox - These are all configured by non-administrator users. They are set to run on a schedule, not by triggers.